# getcount returning 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Hey guys this is my code to compare a name with something existing in the database already. However the getcount returns 0 all the time. Any help ? thanks !!

```
public String checkUserName(SQLiteDatabase db, String enteredName)

{

        String selectionArgs[] = new String[1];
        selectionArgs[0] = enteredName;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table1 where user=?", selectionArgs);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return Integer.toString(cursor.getCount());
    }
```

The code i use to call the above function is :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE)
tv1.setText(db.checkUserName(db.getWritableDatabase(), message));
relativeLayout.addView(tv1)
```

DB snapshot link :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnTbl.jpg

Comment: There is no need of moveToFirst, you can check directlly getCount from the cursor

Comment: @AlexBcn - hmm yea just noticed that, even if i remove it though the getcount returns 0

Comment: Code seems fine. Make sure that your table actually contains this data, and check that enteredName matches exactly.

Comment: the datatype of user in table1 is text. does that work ? or is there any other datatype in sqlite3 that im forgetting ? another thing, the app works fine, my logcat shows: 06-30 18:52:36.974: E/Trace(744): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) might this be an issue ? @KenWolf

Comment: That trace error is fine, datatype text is fine. You should do some debugging, check enteredName is correct, or try and get a result with hardcoding a value, something's going wrong somewhere there.

Comment: @KenWolf okay ty man..just found out that getCount works when i compare _id and 1 or 2 but not for any of the text fields..hardcoding anything in selectionArgs[] did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was wrong..

modified code as :

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table1 where user like ?", selectionArgs);
```

with LIKE in sqlite, 'string%' is used to compare two column entries in addition to the above method